# Adding documents when using a template

Tags: docusignapi

I have created a template in my DocuSign account. As the UI requires, I have uploaded a document.

I have been trying to create a transaction using this template, however, I need to add documents to this transaction, on top of the ones provided in the template.

Looking at the [DocuSign Template documentation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/templates), it doesn't seem possible as it is mentioned : *To apply a template to an envelope you must set the templateId and templateRoles properties in your envelope definition. Since the template contains document(s) already you do not need to configure the documents node.*

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [composite templates](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/templates#composite) and specify a new document in addition to the documents present in the server template.

```
{
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "compositeTemplateId": "1",
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "templateId": "<Specify the server template Id here>"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "name": "Recipient One",
                                "email": "recipientone@foo.com",
                                "roleName": "Signer", //This is the role name in the server template
                                "recipientId": "1"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "compositeTemplateId": "2",
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "2"
                }
            ],
            "document": {
                "documentId": "3", //Make sure this documentId is different from the document's present in the server template.
                "name": "DocumentThree",
                "fileExtension": "txt",
                "documentBase64": "RG9jIFRXTyBUV08gVFdP"
            }
        }

    ],
    "emailSubject": "Adding a new doc with composite templates",
    "status": "created"
}
```

Comment: Nice, can I add recipients in the composite template #2 for the added documents ?

Comment: You can specify recipients and tabs in composite template. Please be aware of the [rules](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#composite-templates) for how the recipients and tabs will be merged. _"Recipient matching is based on Recipient Role and Routing Order. If there are matches, the recipient information is merged together. A final pass is done on all Composite Templates, after all template overlays have been applied, to collapse recipients with the same email, username and routing order. This prevents having the same recipients at the same routing order."_

Comment: It doesn't seem that I can add recipient but instead, it is asking me to ask templateRoles : "message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. 'recipients' may not be specifed when 'templateId' is set. Use 'templateRoles'."

Comment: Please add your Json so that I can tell what you are doing wrong. You can definitely add additional recipients using composite templates.

Comment: Nevermind, I had made the mistake to specify the id template in the envelope and forgot it is already filled in the composite template list